# How to use map function for below input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The React component is getting data via props but not able to render using map function:

[image]

The component code is as follows:

```
function PlaceList(props) {
  console.log(props.places);
  
  return (
    <p>
    {props.places.map((place) => {
          return (
            <ol>  
              <li>{place.id}</li>
              <li>{place.title}</li>
              <li>{place.imp}</li>
            </ol>

          );
    })}
   </p>   
  );
}

export default PlaceList;
```

The data can be seen on console:

[image]

Comment: `props.places`, as shown in the logs, is an _object_. It's not an array, it doesn't have a map method.

Comment: Can you help me convert it ? Am a total beginner !

Comment: It seems like you want to map over the array _in_ that object, so have a think about how to access that.

Answer (score 1):

As from the screenshot, you should iterate over `body` property of `props.places`, which you can do by:

```
return (
<p>
{props.places.body.map((place) => {
      return (
        <ol>  
          <li>{place.id}</li>
          <li>{place.title}</li>
          <li>{place.imp}</li>
        </ol>

      );
})}
```

);